# How can I get multiple json data from json file one by one?

Tags: java, json, json-simple

I am trying to get specific value from json file. Here is my json file.

```
{
  "books": ["book1","book2","book3","book4"],
  "set_with_ratio": {
    "tweaks_es": "7",
    "ratio": {
      "brand_defined_sets_ratio": {
        "default": {
          "desktop": {
            "16": "85",
            "11": "95",
            "19": "10",
            "12": {
              "2": "50"
            }
          }
        },
        "rentals": {
          "desktop": {
            "16": "75",
            "11": "45",
            "12": {
              "2": "10"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I get `books` array elements one by one? I tried this.

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(jsonData);
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("books");
//Iterating the images of the array
Iterator<Object> iterator = jsonArray.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
 System.out.println(iterator.next());
 }
```

From this I got this error `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.JSONArray`
how can I get data for `x.set_with_ratio.ratio.brand_defined_sets_ratio.default.desktop.11` this json path. I am trying this code in Java.

```java
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        try {
            //Parsing the contents of the JSON file
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(new FileReader("sample.json"));
            String id = jsonObject.get("set_with_ratio").toString();
            System.out.println(id);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Here I get the total json file but cannot manage to get expected result.

Comment: @smile Please answer the question

Comment: Follow this link i hope it will help you `https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/parse-json-java/`

Comment: Please refer @ProGamer's answer

Comment: Are you using JSON.simple library in example?

Comment: ` <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20171018</version>
        </dependency>
`
I am using this dependency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.junit.Test;


public class JavaTest {
    @Test
    public void name() {
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        try {
            //Parsing the contents of the JSON file
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse("{\n" +
                    "  \"set_with_ratio\": {\n" +
                    "    \"tweaks_es\": \"7\",\n" +
                    "    \"ratio\": {\n" +
                    "      \"brand_defined_sets_ratio\": {\n" +
                    "        \"default\": {\n" +
                    "          \"desktop\": {\n" +
                    "            \"16\": \"85\",\n" +
                    "            \"11\": \"95\",\n" +
                    "            \"19\": \"10\",\n" +
                    "            \"12\": {\n" +
                    "              \"2\": \"50\"\n" +
                    "            }\n" +
                    "          }\n" +
                    "        },\n" +
                    "        \"rentals\": {\n" +
                    "          \"desktop\": {\n" +
                    "            \"16\": \"75\",\n" +
                    "            \"11\": \"45\",\n" +
                    "            \"12\": {\n" +
                    "              \"2\": \"10\"\n" +
                    "            }\n" +
                    "          }\n" +
                    "        }\n" +
                    "      }\n" +
                    "    }\n" +
                    "  }\n" +
                    "}");
            String id = ((JSONObject) ((JSONObject) ((JSONObject) ((JSONObject) ((JSONObject) jsonObject.get("set_with_ratio"))
                    .get("ratio"))
                    .get("brand_defined_sets_ratio"))
                    .get("default"))
                    .get("desktop"))
                    .get("11" +
                    "").toString();
            System.out.println(id);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Result is `95`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
JSONTokener parser = new JSONTokener(new FileReader("sample.json"));
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(parser);
String id = jsonObject.getJSONObject("set_with_ratio").getJSONObject("ratio").getJSONObject("brand_defined_sets_ratio").getJSONObject("default").getJSONObject("desktop").getString("11");
```

Library used : org.json

Comment: are you importing org.json?

Comment: yes I import it.
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

Comment: Try these : import org.json.JSONObject;  import org.json.JSONTokener; (in case of Tokener).  Dont use org.json.simple library

Comment: Check for This dependency : <dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20190722</version>
</dependency>