# How to parse JSON String to String in Java

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON string, how can I parse it and just get the valueString in java?

```
{
"resourceType": "Bundle",
"id": "0",
"entry": [
    {
        "resource": {
            "resourceType": "Basic",
            "extension": [
                {
                    "url": "http://ith.sahra.com/extensions#uploadid",
                    "valueString": "1589355494289_655"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

}

This is my code, I tried to call extension I got null but I got response while calling entry

```
 public static String ParsingValue(String valuepass) throws org.json.simple.parser.ParseException{
    Object obj = new JSONParser().parse(valuepass);
    JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) obj;
    //JSONArray msg = (JSONArray) jo.getClass();
    JSONArray result = (JSONArray) jo.get("entry");
}
```

Comment: Do you want to parse json from file to a `String` in Java?

Comment: See if this helps For file : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61766498/11537839

Comment: `gson.fromJSON` ? Did you try anything before posting this question?

Comment: of course, I did some research, I try to get extension array but I got the null result, the only array I can get is an entry

Comment: i'm asking this because i can get 1 array but array in array i can't

Comment: Then please show us your code.  The code where you are getting *"the null result, the only array I can get is an entry"*.   Because your current question *reads* like you are just asking us to write code for you.

Comment: I already edited it, thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: thankyou this is helping me to parse it, thank you, everyone, for your kindness

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to parse a string through Jackson parser

Eg:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = "{\"name\":\"anshul\",\"age\":29}";
Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(json, Map.class);
```

Try this, it should solve your problem.

Comment: thankyou so much, i already solved the problem with the reference of your code

Comment: One more point to note here is, if you have a POJO and JSON string is structured as per POJO you can directly parse it in a POJO.
eg: 

```

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = "{\"name\":\"anshul\",\"age\":29}";
User user = mapper.readValue(json, User.class);

```

Comment: I was searching for how to read a bare string, and `mapper.readValue("\"json string\"", String.class)` is what I was looking for. This makes me miss JS/TS a little bit :D